# How to use select2 component in blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor

hello community I am trying to use the select2 component in blazor, I took an example from github but the truth is I am lost in how to fill the component with the records from the database

this is the razor page and this is the component:

```
<span>Simple string example</span>
<Select2 TItem="string"
         Id="simple-string-example"
         Data="@SimpleStringList"
         @bind-Value="@ValueSelected">
</Select2>
<span>Currently selected value: @ValueSelected</span>
<br />

@code {

    private EditContext EditContext { get; set; }
    private Select2<SomeInnerObject> ProvidedSelect2Ref { get; set; }
    public SomeObject FakeObject { get; set; } = new SomeObject { SomeName = "Name" };
    private List<string> SimpleStringList { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    private List<SomeInnerObject> InnerObjectList { get; set; }
    private string ValueSelected { get; set; }

    private SomeInnerObject FooObject = new SomeInnerObject { InnerName = "Inner Foo" };

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
        if (firstRender)
        {
            SimpleStringList.Add("Foo");
            SimpleStringList.Add("Bar");
            SimpleStringList.Add("Baz");

            InnerObjectList = new List<SomeInnerObject> { FooObject, new SomeInnerObject { InnerName = "Inner bar" } };
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                InnerObjectList.Add(new SomeInnerObject { InnerName = $"Inner bar{i}" });
            EditContext = new EditContext(FakeObject).AddDataAnnotationsValidation();
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }   
}
```

[image]

How could you fill the component with records from the database, calling an api in a controller, something like this:

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<Persona>> BuscarPersonas(string searchText)
    {
        var responseHttp = await repositorio.Get<List<Persona>>($"api/Personas/buscar/{searchText}");
        return responseHttp.Response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Test of result

[image]

**Here is example of Blazor(client) and WebAPI(server).**

> *Client Side(Blazor)*

**1. Bind `List<Persona>` to `Select2` and fetch data from `PersonaService`.**
Codes of `Index.razor`

```
@page "/"
@using System.Linq
@using Demo.WebAssembly.Models
@using Demo.WebAssembly.Data


@inject PersonaService service

<span>Simple string example</span>
<Select2 TItem="Persona"
         Id="simple-string-example"
         Data="@personas"
         TextExpression="@(item => item.Name)"
         @bind-Value="@ValueSelected">
</Select2>

<span>Currently selected Inner value: @(ValueSelected?.Name)</span>


<br />

@code
{ 

    private Persona ValueSelected { get; set; } = new Persona { Name = "Name" };

    private List<Persona> personas { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var personaList = await service.BuscarPersonas("user");

        personas = personaList.ToList();

    }


    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
        if (firstRender)
        {

            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Request data from url("https://localhost:44307/api/Personas/buscar/{searchText}")**

Codes of `PersonaService`

```
public class PersonaService
{

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Persona>> BuscarPersonas(string searchText)
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:44307/api/Personas/buscar/" + searchText);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Persona[]>(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return null; //handle the response that was not successful here.
        }
    }

}
```

> *Server Side(WebAPI)*

**1. receive and handle the request. return data in `json` format.**

Codes of `Controller`

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/api/Personas/buscar/{searchText}")]
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetPersona(string searchText)
    {
        var personas = _repository.getPersona(searchText);

        return new JsonResult(personas);
    }
```

**2. Retrieve Data From Database.**

Codes of `Repository`

```
    public List<Persona> getPersona(string searchText)
    {
        var personas = _context.Personas.Where(p=>p.Name.Contains(searchText)).ToList(); 

        return personas;
    }
```

Notes: If access data from other domain(https://localhost:44379) like the example above, don't forget to enable [CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#enable-cors).

Links: [Create a web API with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help, it worked perfectly for me, although I did not understand very well about using PersonaService

Comment: @JasielTorres Did you implement it exactly in the same way than the accepted answer? Somehow its not working for me. I've managed to populate the Data object (personas) but is not refreshing the options on the select2 component